# pop up progress bar of a playing video only on touching the screen

Tags: android, video, progress-bar

I would like to create a progress bar for my video in such a way that while playing the video in full screen user wouldn't be able to see this progress bar but on touching the screen the progress bar should get pop up. Can any one help me please..

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

although launching a video with standard `ACTION_VIEW` intent behave in this way by default .
 but rather you are interested in creating entire View by your own , set a `touchListener` on `rootView` and toggle visibility of `progressbar` ( which is a child of this root view ) on touch .

**Action_View example**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much.. As you told, I have used touchListener and toggled the visibility of progressbar. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use ACTION_VIEW intent to launch a video.. Thank you..

Comment: Thank you.but may I tell you one-thing. I want to play a 3gp video file in my sdcard. So what will be the code for that. Here in your code instead of the variable 'url' i have given a path like "/mnt/sdcard/riseup.3gp" but it throws error. Can you please help me... Thank you..

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/riseup.3gp"));
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: [2012-01-03 10:14:25 - VideoFirst] Starting activity org.video.VideoFirstActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-01-03 10:14:25 - VideoFirst] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.video/.VideoFirstActivity }
[2012-01-03 10:14:25 - VideoFirst] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
[2012-01-03 10:14:44 - VideoFirst] ------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the progress bar layout view between visible and invisible states to show/hide when user taps on screen.

To achieve popup type display use animation effects (In animation and Out animation for layout).

This is my suggestion only, i didn't tried this. But it may helpful to you please try this.